# Ubuntu just load desktop on recovery mode

Tags: boot, drivers, amd-graphics

I download Ubuntu Mate yesterday and installed amd catalyst 13.1 driver on it, after that, when i tried to turn on, it load but only by console and the desktop interface doesn't, then i tried to open by Ubuntu recovery mode, and it load with desktop interface, but when i tried again to turn it without recovery mode again the same problem, just load by console.